# Understanding std::move and Ownership Transfer with std::unique_ptr in C++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have written two sets of functions, F1/test1 and F2/test2 and I'm trying to understand the differences in the behavior of std::move and the transfer of ownership with std::unique_ptr in these functions. Here is the code:

```
void F1(std::unique_ptr<Dog>&& uPtr)
{
    std::cout << "F1 \n";
}

void test1()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> pD(new Dog("Gunner"));
    F1(std::move(pD));
    if (pD == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Null\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Test \n";
}

void F2(std::unique_ptr<Dog> uPtr)
{
    std::cout << "F2 \n";
}

void test2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> pD(new Dog("Smokey"));
    F2(std::move(pD));
    if (pD == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Null\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Test \n";
}
```

In test1, F1 is called with std::move(pD) as the argument, where uPtr is an rvalue reference to std::unique_ptr. After the call to F1, I checked if pD is null. I was expecting that pD would be null because std::move(pD) was used to pass it to F1, but it's not null. Why is this the case?

In test2, F2 is called with std::move(pD) as the argument, where uPtr is a by-value parameter of type std::unique_ptr. After the call to F2, I checked if pD is null. In this case, pD is null. This is as I expected because std::move(pD) was used to pass it to F2, but why is this behavior different from test1?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Those things are based on conventions. `std::move(x)` is an offer to the receiving code to move the object, but whoever receives the value isn't obliged to move. (E.g. if you discard the result of `std::move`, it has no effect.) Having `T &&` as a parameter signals that you might move whatever is passed to you, but it doesn't oblige you to. But having `T` as a parameter forces you to copy/move whatever is passed to you.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation. We can say with F1, std::unique_ptr is passed by rvalue reference, which simply provides another name as alias for pD without changing ownership as no move operator gets involved.

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast to rvalue reference. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object is not moved until a call to the move constructor or the move assignment operator is done. `std::move` is only a cast operator from an lvalue to an rvalue, no data is actually moved at that point. A better name for `std::move` would be `std::cast_to_rvalue` but that would be a bit verbose.

For `F1`, the pointer is passed by rvalue *reference* so the function is still using the instance from the caller. Since `uPtr` is untouched in the function, the original pointer will still be valid.

For `F2`, the pointer is passed by value so the move constructor will have to be called before entering the function to create the new object. Even though the pointer is untouched in the function, the move operation has already taken place so the instance of the caller is affected.

Comment: So, it means the main difference between the two is in how the std::unique_ptr is passed to the function and what happens to the ownership of the Dog instance. With F1, std::unique_ptr is passed by rvalue reference, which simply provides another name as alias for pD without changing ownership as no move operator gets involved. In contrast, F2 accepts a std::unique_ptr by value, causing the ownership of the Dog instance to move from pD to the new std::unique_ptr (uPtr).

Comment: @Sam That's correct

Answer (score 1):

This is just a conversion to an r-value reference

```
F1(std::move(pD));
```

The

```
void F1(std::unique_ptr<Dog>&& uPtr)
{
    std::cout << "F1 \n";
}
```

Doesn't actually do anything to uPtr. It can assume the std_ptr is about to be destroyed and leave it in a indeterminate but valid state. Yours does not do that.

`F2` is using the move constructor, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr look at constructor 5.